# removing/detaching duplicate entity from local context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am `detaching` every student entity from `local context`. The following code works fine and `detach` every entry of student entity from local context.

```
_context.Set<Students>().Local.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    _context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached;
});
```

What if i just need to remove/detach only duplicate entry of Student from local context? How i can do that?

I am using EF 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Easier to check when adding that it isn't a duplicate.

But just group, skip the first and detach the rest?

```
_context.Set<Students>()
        .Local
        .ToList()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .SelectMany(g=>g.Skip(1))
        .ForEach(x =>
{
     _context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached;
});
```